# Getting makefile to change output executable name

Tags: c++, makefile

I am writing a makefile for a school assignment and am having some issues. I can't seem to get the output executable to be named what I want using the -o flag. Instead it is creating an executable named a.out (which is functioning properly).

When I use the "make clean" command, it tells me that my executable name that I want does not exist. I am confused with how the "make" command isn't recognizing the program name and the "make clean" command is. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
 PROGRAM = osuSystem
 CXX = g++
 CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x

 SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
 OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
 HEADERS = $(wildcard *.hpp)

 default: ${OBJECTS}
       ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${HEADERS] ${SOURCES} -o ${PROGRAM}

 clean:
       rm ${OBJECTS} ${PROGRAM}
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you move `-o ${PROGRAM}` to the front? `-o ${PROGRAM} ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS}...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `default: ${OBJECTS}` line tells make to compile all your sources into `.o` files, so the next line need only link the `.o`s and shouldn't mention the source files:

```
default: ${OBJECTS}
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} -o ${PROGRAM}
```

I reproduced your problem locally and this change got it working.  For clean, you should use `rm -f` so it doesn't complain and removes those that do exist when you run `clean` while some of the objects/program to delete don't exist.

Comment: The `-c` option means to create only `.o` files. Where do you see that?

Comment: @Barmar Make knows how to compile a .cpp file into a .o, and will do it implicitly when you specify the objects as dependencies for a target; above, the relevant target is "`default`".  If `default` were dependent on the `${SOURCES}` instead of `${OBJECTS}`, *then* the `default` build steps would need to compile up the `.cpp`s explicitly.